# Turn off msg-generation for lisp

Tags: ros, messages, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!

I'm currently trying to speed up my build process and just notices the generation of lisp files for my msg/action-files.
Is there a simple way to turn that off? Or are they somehow used internally?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213511/turn-off-msg-generation-for-lisp/) by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3519 on 2015-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is fully documented on the wiki. See [wiki/ROS/EnvironmentVariables - ROS_LANG_DISABLE](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables#ROS_LANG_DISABLE):

> A colon-separated list of package names for message generators / client libraries that should be disabled. Message-generation will not happen for languages in this list.

> For packages build with **catkin** you need to list the names of the message generators which should be ignored, e.g.:

> ```
> export ROS_LANG_DISABLE=genlisp
> ```

It then goes on to say:

> Note that before disabling a language, you should first be very sure that none of the code you're using requires that language's bindings.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-07-12**:
"This is fully documented on the wiki." If you know where you have to look ;) Thanks!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-07-12**:
I found that using Google: "ros disable message generator", first hit ;)

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2015-07-12**:
okay, then I really should have tried longer..

**Comment by [CroCo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4955/croco/) on 2022-05-10**:
still not informative enough. What need to be done to disable them?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-10**:
If you're sure you're still using ROS 1, basically:

```
export ROS_LANG_DISABLE=genlisp
```

before building your workspace. That would disable Lisp.

Please refer to the wiki for the available information.